# How to update code from Jmockit 1.1 to 1.9 to Access Real Instance?

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I am trying to update code from `Jmockit` 1.1 to 1.9 to Access Real Instance, But it seems to be unsuccessful as below:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Matching real methods not found for the following mocks:
CopyOfAccessRealInstanceTest$1#getRealInstanceName(String m, mockit.Invocation inv)
    at CopyOfAccessRealInstanceTest$1.<init>(CopyOfAccessRealInstanceTest.java:28)
    at CopyOfAccessRealInstanceTest.mockConstructor(CopyOfAccessRealInstanceTest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

I think it is due to mock method:

```
        @Mock(invocations = 1)
        public String getRealInstanceName(String m,Invocation inv)
```

-------------------------Codes 1.9---------------------------------

```
public class CopyOfAccessRealInstanceTest {  
    private Constructor constructor = new Constructor("");  

    @Test
    public void mockConstructor() {
        // Mockit.setUpMock(Constructor.class, new MockedConstructor());
        MockUp<Constructor> mockup = new MockUp<Constructor>() {
            //public Constructor it;

            @Mock(invocations = 1)
            public String getRealInstanceName(String m,Invocation inv)
            {           
                if ("real".equals(m)) {
                    return inv.proceed(inv.getInvokedArguments());
                    // return it.getRealInstanceName(m);
                } else {
                    return "mock";
                }
            }
        };

        Assert.assertEquals("mock",
                                constructor.getRealInstanceName(""));
        Assert.assertEquals("real_m_real",
            constructor.getRealInstanceName("real"));
    }
}
```

-----------------------Code of Jmock 1.1--------------------------------

```
public class AccessRealInstanceTest {
    private Constructor constructor = new Constructor("");

    @Test
    public void mockConstructor() {
        Mockit.setUpMock(Constructor.class, new MockedConstructor());
        Assert.assertEquals("real_m_real",
                   constructor.getRealInstanceName("real"));
    }

    public static class MockedConstructor {
        public Constructor it;
        @Mock(reentrant = true)//reentrant allow to access real instance
        public String getRealInstanceName(String m) {
            if ("real".equals(m)) {
                return it.getRealInstanceName(m);
            } else {
                return "mock";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class to be Mocked:

```
public class Constructor {
    private String memberId;  

    public Constructor(String memberId) {  
        this.memberId = memberId;  
    }  

    public String getRealName() {  
        return "real_" + this.memberId;  
    }  

    public String getRealInstanceName(String m) {
        return "real_m_" + m;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not successful? What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I've update the description in exception part at the top. Thanks.

Comment: What is the code at **line 28** in your `CopyOfAccessRealInstanceTest` class?

Comment: It is "MockUp<Constructor> mockup = new MockUp<Constructor>() {". Btw, the code are all in the description, you can build it in eclipse just include the jars(Jmockit,Junit,Jdk).

Comment: Note the API documentation says that an `Invocation` parameter must be the *first* parameter in the mock method.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It works! Thank you for Rogério and Sean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is resolved. Thank you for [Rogério](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2326914/rog%C3%A9rio) and [Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1314132/sean-mickey)!

Note the API documentation says that an Invocation parameter must be the first parameter in the mock method. –  [Rogério](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2326914/rog%C3%A9rio)